# Compare element values and assign attribute to larger

Tags: javascript, jquery

'Ive been banging my head trying to figure out the best way to go about this...

I have this HTML:

```
<div id="aa1">23</div>
<div id="a2">14</div>

<div id="b1">67</div>
<div id="bb2">21</div>
```

What I am attempting to do is to compare the value of these elements in pairs.  Easiest solution would be:

```
var a1 = parseFloat($("#aa1").text()).toFixed(2);
var a2 = parseFloat($("#a2").text()).toFixed(2);
var b1 = parseFloat($("#b1").text()).toFixed(2);
var b2 = parseFloat($("#bb2").text()).toFixed(2);

if (a1 > a2){
    $('#aa1').css('color','#fff');
}else{
    $('#a2').css('color','#fff');
}

if (b1 > b2){
    $('#b1').css('color','#fff');
}else{
    $('#bb2').css('color','#fff');
}
```

Assuming that the div IDs will not be the same length, will contain numbers, and there will be multiple pairs, although the pairing will always be the same (always a1/a2, b1/b2, etc),  what would be the best way to go about this?  Ive tried a few different solutions (substring, regex, Math.max), but hit a different roadblock with each.

Edit:

John S set me in the right direction.  The js that I ended up using was:

```
//Grabbing initial values.  Yes, these could be assigned in the next section.
var a1 = parseFloat($("#aa1").text()).toFixed(2);
var a2 = parseFloat($("#a2").text()).toFixed(2);
var b1 = parseFloat($("#b1").text()).toFixed(2);
var b2 = parseFloat($("#bb2").text()).toFixed(2);

//Setting up the pairs.  Note the additional - character to enable the ability to split correctly.
var arr1 = ['aa1-'+a1, 'a2-'+a2];
var arr2 = ['b1-'+b1, 'bb2-'+b2];
//Creating the two-demensional array
var mainarr = [arr1, arr2];

//Loop through each pair in the array
for (var i=0; i < mainarr.length; i++){
//Split off the values I want
var first = mainarr[i][0].split('-')[1], second = mainarr[i][1].split('-')[1];
//Split off the html IDs I want
var firstCss = '#'+mainarr[i][0].split('-')[0], secondCss = '.'+mainarr[i][1].split('-')[0];
//compare pairs and assign the correct attribute to the element.
((first > second) ? $(firstCss) : $(secondCss)).css('background-color','#DBFFDB');
}
```

Still have to initially setup the pairs, but this is way better than a million if/else statements.

Comment: How would you suggest _guessing_ that `a1` is actually `aa1`? How do you find the pairs? This seems like a problem you shouldn't be having. Is there any way you can set up the HTML to make it more obvious which elements are pairs?

Comment: Well, right.  Thats the problem I was running into.  Unfortunately I can't modify the css classes, one of the roadblocks I was hitting.  I tried creating a two dimensional array of the pairs ([[a1,a2], [b1, b2]]) and then iterating through that, and it worked perfectly to find the higher of the two pairs and perform an action based on the result.  But the problem with that was then, like you mentioned, trying to guess what element the action was supposed to apply to.

Comment: Can you change the HTML?

Comment: Nope.  Thats the issue I was running into with trying to use substring.

Comment: When you tried the two dimensional array, was it an array of the computed values, instead of the elements? If you made it of the elements, then I would think it would work for you. You would compute the values when you are iterating through the array, not while you are building the array..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you just loop through the elements two at a time:

```
function value($div) {
    return parseFloat($div.text()).toFixed(2);
}

var $divs = $('div'); // Use whatever selector gets all the desired elements
for (var i = 0; i < $divs.length; i += 2) {
    var $div1 = $divs[i], $div2 = $divs[i + 1];
    ((value($div1) > value($div2)) ? $div1 : $div2).css('color','#fff');
}
```

Comment: Awesome.  This was pretty much what I was hoping for.  I ended up modifying this answer a bit, but the general idea was exactly what worked for me.  Thanks!